Remove Cypress dependency from higher environments
I have cypress as a dependency in my package.json for my next.js app. Cypress is installing some dependencies that have security vulnerabilities when it does a yarn install. I really only need Cypress to run tests on my codebuild server and not on my test/pilot servers. Is there a way to remove the dependency in certain environments?

Add is as a devDependency, then use the production build for your pilot server.

This question is similar to: What's the difference between dependencies, devDependencies, and peerDependencies in NPM package.json file?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thank you both for the insights. I was able to move the cypress package to dev deps and use node_env=production to solve the issue.
